# BibTeX - do NOT sort authors

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

Is there any way to tell bibtex not to sort the authors for a paper but to print them in the order they've been written in the .bib-file?

I have a paper where three people from three different institutions collaborated and I should like to keep the author order in sync with the institution order.

Edit: the citation in question

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\title{...}
\author{...}

%%Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\cite{ChalicePaper}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bib}

\end{document}
```

Bib File:

```
@TechReport{ChalicePaper,
author = {K.Rustan M. Leino, Peter M\"uller, Jan Smans},
title = {Verification of Concurrent Programs with Chalice},
institution = {Microsoft Research, ETH Z\"urich, KU Leuven},
year = {2009}
}
```

I want them to appear in that order. What the parsed pdf looks like in the "References" is this:

> Jan Smans K.Rustan M. Leino, Peter Müller.   Veriﬁcation of concurrent programs with chalice. Technical report, Microsoft Research, ETH
>   Zürich, KU Leuven, 2009.

Comment: Isn't it the default dehavior?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: We will need an example of your input (`.tex` and `.bib` files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the main bibliography, then use

```
[...]
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
[...]
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibfile}
[...]
```

same as style `plain` but without sorting the entries.
If you mean a single bib entry then use:

```
author = {K. Rustan and M. Leino and Peter M\"uller and Jan Smans},
```

[image]

Comment: nope, doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Well, what more can I say? I already edited the question to include the example you were asking for.

Comment: @User1291: See my edited answer. Your author list in the bibfile was wrong